# How to execute function while handle 2 events at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that wants to be executed while the user resizing an element and scrolling the window at the same time tow events must occur at the same time to execute the function something like the following but I want to merge them to be like one custom event?

```
this.on("resize", function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    figure.setHeight(_this.getHeight());
  _this.setHeight(figure.getHeight());
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code implies that only after the element resize event is fired, a scroll event listener should be attached to the window object. This does not mean the window scroll event listener is executed, only attached. Try attaching the windows scroll event listener outside of the element resize event listener.

Comment: there's something i don't understand. These 2 events can't trigger at the same time. Firstly the user has to start resizing the element and then scroll, right ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the resize event is triggered first, and then if the user also scrolls your custom function should be called

```js
let resizeTriggered = false

const myResizeFunc = (event) => {
resizeTriggered = true
}

const myScrollFunc = (event) => {
  if (resizeTriggered) {
    myCustomFunction()
  }
}

const myCustomFunction = () => {
    console.log('both are happening')
}

$('#textArea').mousedown(myResizeFunc)
$(window).scroll(myScrollFunc)
```

```css
div.large {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
<div class="large">

</div>
```

Comment: if I do that the function will be executed on any event of them I want it to be executed while two events are occurring at the same time

Comment: @MihaiT I had posted similar solution. I don't know how both can happen at same time :(

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation :** I have used a flag here, initially set to `false`. As it is given that both events will be happening, we can make a check in one function is the other is happening or not and execute the desired function.

First of all click the button. A console will be generated, that `clicked`. Now flag is set to true. But `myFunction()` is not eecuted, coz it will fire only when `keydown` will take place. In case key is pressed, `flag` won't be `true`, and hence `myFunction()` will not be executed. Now that you know that, button was clicked, so it has the focus. On pressing `enter` key, it will do perform `click` and `keydown` at same time. And `myFunction()` will get executed. When it gets executed, set flag to false. :)

```js
var flag = false;

$(document).on("keydown", function() {
  flag = true;
  console.log("key pressed");
});

$('button').click(function() {
  console.log("clicked");
  if (flag) {
    myFunction();
  }
});

function myFunction() {
  alert("Both at same time");
  flag = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: if you start to resize and move the mouse to the bottom of the screen to make auto-scroll the resize event will stop so with this solution, you have to continue moving the mouse in the dom to make it work

Comment: @SamaNoov Can you please enlighten me how can both events happen at same time?

Comment: that what I am trying to do I want to write a function that when I resize something and scroll the screen while I resizing  add scrolling value to its size

Comment: @SamaNoov I am not talking about the implementation. I am asking that how can you resize an element, and scroll through it at same time?

Comment: scroll down the mouse wheel while you resizing for example or you can move the mouse to the bottom of the screen while you clicking to make auto-scroll